# Create post with one category on eloquent laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to create post with one category by user, my table

```
user
id_user

category
id_category

post
id_post
user_id
category_id
```

This is my models

```
//User.php
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
//Post.php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
//Category.php
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

and the `Request`:

```
//CreatePostRequest.php
class CreatePostRequest extends Request {

public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required:min',
        'description' => 'required',
        'category_list' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

}

I have tried

```
$post= Auth::user()->post()->create($request->all());
```

But have error "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laravelproj`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id_category`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `description`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Can buy somethingLorem ipsum dolor sit amet4, 2015-12-08 06:47:42, 2015-12-08 06:47:42, ?, ?))".
How to solve this? Sorry for bad english

Comment: Sorry, it was updated

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error when creating a **Post** is that there is no category in the database that would match the **id_category** that you pass to **create()**.

Comment: That is exist with same type int(10) too

Comment: It's not about a column that does not exist. It's that the category_id that you get from $request->all() and pass to create() does not match an existing id_category in category table.

Comment: Could you paste what you're getting from $request->all() and the whole error you're getting?

Comment: @jadrzej.kurylo like that?

Comment: The query you're executing is "insert into posts (title, description, user_id, updated_at, created_at)" - you can see category_id missing.

Comment: Either there is no "category_id" field in what is returned from $request->all() and passed to create() OR "category_id" is not on the list of fillable fields for this model ($fillable attribute).

Comment: @jadrzej.kurylo so how to add "category_id" in what is returned from $request->all() and passed to create() ?

Comment: Come on, how should I know where you want to take that value from? it's your app. When user creates a post, how do they define what category the post belongs to? Take that value from there.

Comment: @jadrzej.kurylo it solved with adding `array_add($request->all(), 'category_id', $request->input('category_list')));` in create(). Maybe have better solution?

Comment: Why not just rename the input in your form to 'category_id'? That would be much easier if it's possible, you'd get that value directly in the $request->all()